# Adding a constraint to stop a user from updating some fields when importing the data with its generated external id

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I want to add a constraint but I don't have the idea of how to do it. I created a custom export which auto-generates external ids for each record I export. The export contains a list of students which the lecturer has to update their marks.. and re-imports the same excel sheet which also updates the marks of the students.

However much there is some information which I don't want the lecturers to update but I have failed to restrict the lecturer from importing the data in case those field values have been updated.

Any Ideas,  Thank you.

Comment: Could you post the code of import did you use a method ?

Comment: Hello @CharifDZ, I am using the default Odoo import process. Of clicking on the import button and upload the excel sheet. The data is being imported but because the external ids in excel match those in the system. so it will update the records in the database. Though their some record fields which I don't want to be updated. That's my main issue.

Answer (score 0):

If a student is a `res.partner` and you're a bit technical (eg: you know how to code in Odoo), you can migrate this module [partner_changeset](https://github.com/OCA/partner-contact/tree/10.0/partner_changeset) to version 12. It's only available for v10 now.

This module allows an administrator to setup rules on some fields of `res.partner` object. With this rule, you can discard changes made by a user or send the change to validation to an "admin".